# Toggle CAMERA flash on the push of a button; AVFoundation/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Im using AVFoundation to create a custom camera. It needs to have a flash button that on press, toggles the flash on and off. I am not asking about torch, there are plenty of answers for torch. Because AVFoundation has been deprecated, most answers online don't work anymore. Also, I need to guard against the possibility the user doesn't have a front flash.

This is the code I have tried with no luck:

```
    private func flashOn(device:AVCaptureDevice)
{
    do{
        if (device.hasFlash)
        {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
            photoSettings.flashMode = .on
            device.flashMode = .on
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }catch{
        //DISABEL FLASH BUTTON HERE IF ERROR
        print("Device tourch Flash Error ");
    }
}

private func flashOff(device:AVCaptureDevice)
{
    do{
        if (device.hasFlash){
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
            photoSettings.flashMode = .off
            device.flashMode = .off
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }catch{
        //DISABEL FLASH BUTTON HERE IF ERROR
        print("Device tourch Flash Error ");
    }
}

func toggleFlash() {
    var device : AVCaptureDevice!

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let videoDeviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInDuoCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .unspecified)!
        let devices = videoDeviceDiscoverySession.devices!
        device = devices.first!

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    }

    if ((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo))
    {
        if (device.hasFlash)
        {
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            //self.objOverlayView.disableCenterCameraBtn();
            if device.isFlashActive == false {
                self.flashOn(device: device)
            } else {
                self.flashOff(device: device);
            }
            //self.objOverlayView.enableCenterCameraBtn();
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call it in my VC

```
    @IBAction func flashBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    toggleFlash()
}
```

Here is what Ive tried:
[How to turn the iPhone camera flash on/off swift 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585353/how-to-turn-the-iphone-camera-flash-on-off-swift-2)

Comment: The would benefit so many people especially since Apple changed the AVFoundation code so old flash code will cause older phones to crash!