# How to print whether camera flash is on on off (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I'm trying to print if flash is on or off or auto via  a button toggle.
It seems I need to use `flashMode from AVCapturePhotoSettings`, however I may not be using switch case properly to get it working.

Here are the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/1648760-flashmode

Here is my attempt:

```
var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
var cameraPreviewlayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
var photoSetting = AVCapturePhotoSetting() 
var image: UIImage? 




@IBAction func flash(_ sender: Any){
        photoSetting = AVCapturePhotoSetting()
    let x = currentCamera!.flashMode
    switch x{
    case. auto:
    print("auto"
    case .off:
    print("off"
    case .on :
  print("on")
```

}

Here I get the error:
`Cannot call non-function type AVCaptureDevice.Flashmode`

EDIT: Removing braces bring up this error:
Expression resolves to an unused l-value

I've looked at several threads including this one:
[Toggle CAMERA flash on the push of a button; AVFoundation/Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599549/toggle-camera-flash-on-the-push-of-a-button-avfoundation-swift)

I still can't figure out the proper way to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: You might want to try using three if statements instead of a switch. I realize this probably isn’t best practice but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Steps :-

```
//Use These Extension



//Mark :-  
extension AVCaptureDevice {

    class func toggleTorch() -> Bool {
        guard let defaultDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .unspecified)
        else {

            return false
        }

        if  defaultDevice.hasTorch {
            print("defaultDevice.hasTorch:", defaultDevice.hasTorch)

            // Lock your default device for configuration
            do {
                // unlock your device when done
                defer {
                    defaultDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
                    print("defaultDevice.unlockedForConfiguration:", true)
                }
                try defaultDevice.lockForConfiguration()
                print("defaultDevice.lockedForConfiguration:", true)
                // Toggles the torchMode
                defaultDevice.torchMode = defaultDevice.torchMode == .on ? .off : .on
                // Sets the torch intensity to 100% if torchMode is ON
                if defaultDevice.torchMode == .on {
                    do {
                        try defaultDevice.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1)
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        print("defaultDevice.torchMode:", defaultDevice.torchMode == .on)
        return defaultDevice.torchMode == .on
    }
}
```

Comment: To Call This :-    

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:))))
    }
    func tap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if AVCaptureDevice.toggleTorch() {
            print("TORCH IS ON")
        } else {
            print("TORCH IS OFF")
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:))))
    }
    func tap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if AVCaptureDevice.toggleTorch() {
            print("TORCH IS ON")
        } else {
            print("TORCH IS OFF")
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

Comment: Thank  you. However torch seems to be the flashlight? I'm talking about flashMode from photoSettings, the camera flash when taking pictures.